# SQL - How to use the same database prefix for multiple table references

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

Brand new to SQL...

I'm trying to write something that starts with:

```
SELECT someColumn
    FROM someTable
```

However, in my particular case, the table has multiple prefixes such that the FROM statement would look more like this:

```
FROM someDatabase.dbo.someTable
```

I'm trying to refactor an existing query that requires multiple joins and thus multiple references to the above path prefix (i.e., `someDatabase.dbo...`).

This seems incredibly inefficient but I can't seem to figure out how to assign a variable that I can reference each time as opposed to referencing the entire path of each table.

Just to be totally clear, the tables all have names that start with `dbo` in SQL Server Studio so the table name is actual `dbo.someTable`, but I believe this is read as if it were an additional prefix but I would be happy either setting `someDatabase` as a default (I tried `USE someDatabase`, which didn't work) or as a short variable (e.g. `@db` to be referenced like `@db.someTable` as a sudo code example).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are joining across databases, you can drop the database prefix (so remove `someDatabase.`).  If your query is running in the context of `dbo`, you can also drop `dbo.` and therefore just put the table name.

Comment: @MartinParkin But I really don't recommend the latter. Saving a few keystrokes is not worth the mess that can create, IMHO.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `USE database` "didn't work"?

Comment: Is the efficiency you're trying to gain simply avoiding typing `database_name` five times, say, in a five-table join?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Of course you are correct (and I always use `dbo.` in my own queries). However it _could_ be used without it if desired.

Comment: @MartinParkin if desired *and* the OP is aware of all potential and unintended side effects. Feel free to do that in your own code, but I strongly recommend not advocating it to all readers here.

Comment: @EricBrandt Probably inside a stored procedure where `USE` is not valid.

Comment: You can't use a variable to represent an entity (or part of the path to an entity). You can do that if you're building your string with dynamic SQL, which isn't a good idea if it's solely to save typing. You can use synonyms but saving a few keystrokes is not a very compelling reason for that abstraction, either.

Comment: Without appending `someDatabase`, I get an `Invalid object name` error.  There are multiple databases in Studio so it would make sense that I would need to specify the database.  I tried `USE someDatabase` with the hope that all table references would be to `someDatabase` but it didn't help.  Also, I have about 30 table references so writing the entire path is very messy.

Comment: Tried `CREATE SYNONYM` as that seemed to be what I was looking for but got a permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're pulling data from multiple databases, there's no getting around *some* tedious typing, but you only need the fully qualified name (database.schema.table) the first time you reference a table in your query. At that point you can (and some, including me, would argue that you *should*) alias your table. After that, you'll only be referencing the table alias, which in this case will also be a database and schema alias.

Very generically speaking, it'll look something like this:

```
SELECT
   bt.ColumnOne
  ,bt.ColumnTwo
  ,dt1.ColumnThree
  ,dt2.ColumnFour
FROM
  database1.dbo.BaseTable as bt
  JOIN
  database2.dbo.DetailTableOne as dt1
    ON dt1.ID = bt.ID
  JOIN
  database3.dbo.DetailTableTwo as dt2
    ON dt2.ColumnWhatever = dt1.ColumnWhatever
WHERE
  dt.YetAnotherColumn = @SomeValue;
```

If you use meaningful aliases it's a simple enough thing to remember what each alias refers to and where it comes from. And you definitely should use meaningful aliases, as Aaron points out in this article that I email to people I work with at least once a week: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if you're using the default schema (`dbo`), you can type two periods and skip over it. I realize this only saves you a little typing (you'd still have to type the database name), but it's something.

```
-- just an example query, not intended to demonstrate anything except the shortcut
SELECT TOP 20 Task.Name,
              User.Name AS Assignee
FROM   TaskDatabase..Task AS Task -- two periods here instead of TaskDatabase.dbo.Task
       INNER JOIN UserDatabase..User AS USER
               ON Task.AssigneeId = User.UserId
ORDER  BY Task.Name
```

I don't think this works for anything but the default schema, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with it being "incredibly inefficient". If you're simply talking about keystrokes, there are any number of addons (or even intellisense) which can save you the time doing the keystrokes. I use a SSMS addon called SSMSToolsPack to bind various code snippets, but Redgate and ApexSql and even VSCode have similar offerings as well.

If you're talking about the code being overly verbose (and thus presumably slower), that's actually not the case. In fact, using a fully qualified name actually *saves* the query processor some time, because it doesn't have to guess at where your object resides and what it thinks you meant by omitting the database and schema.

Either way, getting into the habit of fully qualifying your object names is a good practice.

As far as parameterizing part of the object, as Aaron Bertrand pointed out, that's just not how database objects work, unless you're using dynamic SQL, which is a whole other can of worms I don't recommend you open.

If none of this is satisfactory and you're hellbent on not having to type the database and schema prefix, your options are basically to use [SYNONYMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [VIEWs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The former is about the closest thing you can have to abstracting out a fully qualified name into another format. The latter gives you more control over what the content of the view returns, but even there, you'll have to provide the fully qualified objects in the body of the view.